# Using SUM CASE in chart series

Tags: charts, apex

I have two different chart pages where in one of the pages I create an overview of expenses and incomes per month - all expenses.
In the other one I want to compare this year with the previous year.
The first one was quite easy and I was able to resolve it using only DECODE. For the second one however I believe I needed to use a CASE.

This is where it gets tricky, if I run my query in the SQL commands window it works fine and I get results, but when I use it in my chart series, I get 'no data'.
Could it be the SUM of a CASE is not allowed here?

My working series query:

```
select NULL LINK, to_char(A.ENTRY_DATE, 'MON') LABEL, 
sum(decode(A.EXPENSE_TYPE, ' Expense', A.AMOUNT)) AMOUNT_EXPENSES, 
sum(decode(A.EXPENSE_TYPE, ' Income', A.AMOUNT)) AMOUNT_INCOME
from BUDGET_EXPENSES A, BUDGET_USERS B
WHERE A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
and (B.APPLICATION_USER = nvl(v('APP_USER'),USER)
or B.DIRECT_MANAGER = nvl(v('APP_USER'),USER))
group by to_char(A.ENTRY_DATE, 'MON'),  to_char(A.ENTRY_DATE, 'MM')
order by to_char(A.ENTRY_DATE, 'MM')
```

My non-working series query:

```
select NULL LINK, to_char(A.ENTRY_DATE, 'MON') LABEL, 
sum(case when A.EXPENSE_TYPE = ' Expense' and A.ENTRY_DATE > '01/01/' 
|| to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') then a.amount end) SUM_EXP_THIS_YEAR,
sum(case when A.EXPENSE_TYPE = ' Income' and A.ENTRY_DATE > '01/01/' 
|| to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') then a.amount end) SUM_INC_THIS_YEAR,
sum(case when A.EXPENSE_TYPE = ' Expense' and a.entry_date between '01/01/' 
|| to_char(sysdate -365, 'YYYY') and '01/01/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') then 
a.amount end) SUM_EXP_LAST_YEAR,
sum(case when A.EXPENSE_TYPE = ' Income' and a.entry_date between '01/01/' 
|| to_char(sysdate -365, 'YYYY') and '01/01/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') then 
a.amount end) SUM_INC_LAST_YEAR
from BUDGET_EXPENSES A, BUDGET_USERS B
WHERE A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
and (B.APPLICATION_USER = nvl(v('APP_USER'),USER)
or B.DIRECT_MANAGER = nvl(v('APP_USER'),USER))
group by to_char(A.ENTRY_DATE, 'MON'),  to_char(A.ENTRY_DATE, 'MM')
order by to_char(A.ENTRY_DATE, 'MM')
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: due to the overflow of comments I tinkered some more with it myself.

Comment: due to the overflow of comments I tinkered some more with it myself. The problem was in my sysdate comparison, not in the SUM+CASE, once I concatenated '0101' instead of '01/01' it worked..